# How to efficiently insert a vector into another vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am writing a program that over time creates some vectors and is supposed to add those vectors to another vector, something like this (I cannot make assumptions about the type of data so I write it as T) :

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> result;
std::vector<T> tmp;

while (...) {
     // ... do some transformations to tmp

     result.push_back(tmp);
}
```

Now my question is this: Is there a more efficient way to copy contents from `tmp` to `result`?

EDIT:
I can use `std::vector::reserve` in advance only for the `tmp` vector. The capacity of the result cannot be determined in advance.
Also, the contents of `tmp` must be accessible in the next loop iteration

Comment: @JeJo I still need tmp to hold the data it held before pushing it to the result vector. Won't using move semantics empty the tmp vector?

Comment: @JeJo Yes. The contents of tmp in the next iteration are created based on the previous state.

Comment: As already mentioned, you can use `.reserve()` to prevent unnecessary reallocations in the destination vector. You can also use iterator pairs to insert a range of values in one go rather than pushing in individual values. You cannot avoid copies if you still need the data in the source vector.

Comment: If you really care about performance and not so much about the way you do it, you can keep a 1D vector `std::vector<T> result`. `std::vector<T>` in general consists only of `pointer to some dynamic memory, size and capacity`. Even though you can have 2D vector `std::vector<std::vector<T>> result`, you still need to allocate additional memory that is not contiguous each cycle.
A possible resolution would be having 2 vectors - one containing all the elements, second one is a pair of `start index and end index`. Also use `std::copy` which will optimize your copy based on your types.

Comment: If you use a combination of [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to pre-allocate/pre-construct the needed space of the inner `std::vector` handles and [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) on the `tmp` so it transfers ownership of `tmp` data to the allocated handles.

Comment: @vikAy That is an awesome idea. However, how would I go about optimizing this if I do not know CYCLES in advance? I can only reserve space for the ```tmp``` vector but not for the ```result```

Comment: Do you know the size of the `tmp` vectors at the beginning of each loop or even before?

Comment: @oraqlle The ```tmp``` vector is a fixed size ```N``` which is known before the first iteration of the loop. The ```result``` vector capacity should therefore be some ```M*N``` but the M cannot be known. For further context I am working on an algorithm that lists all possible topological sortings of a graph where ```N``` is the number of vertices. The idea is to construct a sorting in vector ```tmp``` then add it to the ```result``` and continue this process untill all have been examined. As far as I know, there is not a fast way exactly guess the number of such sortings therefore M is unknown

Comment: You can then use the [Size Constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (see #4). This will construct `tmp` and allocate the  needed space however, due to the nature of `std::move` it then gives ownership of this memory to the vectors inside `result` leaving `tmp` in its default initialized state (ie. empty) meaning you would still need to allocate more memory each loop.

Comment: What standard are you using? If you have access to std::ranges or range-v3 you could perform the operations lazily.

Comment: @oraqlle I am on C++17 and can only use what STL gives me and no external libraries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248332/discussion-between-oraqlle-and-themememachine).